# Terraform 'for each' loops over elements which are list of strings, not applying

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm about to create a route table and associate them to subnets, so I've 3 subnets `(list of strings)` they're already created, but when I'm trying to associate a route table to subnets, it's associating only with 1st one, and I guess same issues while I'm trying to associate a `NAT` gateway which is also a `list of strings`.

Here is outputs:

```
  + nat_list = [
      + "nat-0980ffedd5471b76d",
      + "nat-053701e207f6e92b2",
      + "nat-0be06d45baf164edc",
    ]

  + subnets  = [
      + "subnet-04c920f8908d7e502",
      + "subnet-0e9e9333180cab627",
      + "subnet-0caae55b544e4b63d",
    ]
```

Here is my `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
   count  = length(local.azs)
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc[0].id
   tags   = var.tags
} <<< Creating without any problems



resource "aws_route" "public_ipv4"  {
   for_each       = { for route in local.public_ipv4 : route.name => route}
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.*.id
   
   ...  ...
   
   nat_gateway_id         = ??? lookup(each.value, "nat", "" ) Not working ???
   destination_cidr_block = lookup(each.value, "destination_cidr_block", "" )
   
   ...  ...
}



resource "aws_route_table_association" "public"  {
   count          = length(local.azs)
   subnet_id      = lookup(var.parameters[count.index], "public_subnet", [])
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.*.id
}



variable "parameters"                {
   description = "The route table parameters"   
   type        = list(object({
     ... ...
     public_subnet = list(string)
     ... ...
   }))
   default     = []
}
```

Update: Local var

```
locals {
    public_ipv4 = {[
        {
           name = "NAT(s) to MyLogSys ${local.counter + 1 }"
           nat = aws_nat_gateway.translate.*.id 
           destination_cidr_block = "100.0.20.0/20"
        }
    ]}
}
```

I made a research, however it seems there is no similar issue

Comment: What is `local.public_ipv4`?

Comment: Hello @Marcin sorry, forgot to upload, please allow me 2 minutes

Comment: Also I don't understand how `aws_route_table.public` would be "Creating without any problems"? it is incorrect. `vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc` should be `vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id`.

Comment: @Marcin sorry, yes you.re right it is just typo again, while copy paste to portal, it is `vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc[0].id` Let me edit one more time

Comment: Are you sure that this code even executes so you know that only first nat is used? Because  `route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.*.id` is also incorrect.

Comment: @Marcin, it is executes however, I don't know how to use properly `route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.*.id`, Nothing is working as expected in `aws_route_table_association` block I've used  `aws_route_table.public.*.id[count.index]`, in `aws_route` block I've used `aws_route_table.public[0].id`, Nothing is working as expected, so I just pasted last attempt here, but yes I've checked it is not executing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227439/discussion-between-bow-bow-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a chat discussion.

It was suggested to replace:

```
for_each       = { for route in local.public_ipv4 : route.name => route}
```

with

```
for_each       = { for idx, route in local.public_ipv4 : idx => route}
```

where idx will take values `0,1,2,...` based on the size of `local.public_ipv4`.

To protect from accessing elements in the lists which have fewer elements than `local.public_ipv4`, [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) can be used.